# Hide web part that is defined in Site Definition

Tags: web-part, wss-3.0

I am trying to hide or remove a Web Part, a View of a document library, from Webs that have been created using a Site Definition that specifies this View.

In ONET.XML, the following is what sets up the Web Part view.

```
<Modules>
    <Module Name="Default" Url="" Path="">
        <File Url="default.aspx" NavBarHome="True" Type="Ghostable">
            ...
            <View List="Documents" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="3" />
...............
```

When I try and access it via the LimitedWebPartManager, I don't see the Web Part.

Here is the code

```
        using (var web = GetWeb("/path"))
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart toDelete = null;
            using (var wps = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(
                    "default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared))
            {

                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart 
                          webpart in wps.WebParts)
                {
                    if(webpart.Title=="Documents")
                    {
                        toDelete = webpart;
                    }
                }
                if (toDelete != null)
                    wps.DeleteWebPart(toDelete);
            }
        }
```

**More information:**

The web parts are coming back as `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ErrorWebPart` because it is running from a utility rather than a feature or web part.

Comment: Please post the code that you are using.  You should be able to enumerate them (all other things being well).  Do you get any error messages?  Are you sure you have the correct permissions?

Comment: The code is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my solution is to simply move the code to a feature and activate it to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into problems iterating as you're using the `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart` class - not every web part in SharePoint is a SharePoint web part.  Try using the more general `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts` class.

e.g.

```
foreach(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts webpart in wps.WebParts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(webpart.Title);
}
```

Try it in a console app - it tends to be easier to see problems without all the other layers involved.

Also, don't forget that SPLimitedWebPartManager leaks a web, so you should finish off with...

```
try{
    ... Your code ...
}
finally
{
    wps.Web.Dispose();
}
```

As from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_160)